# Why are there so many American phrases about derrières?

Tags: idioms, american-english, offensive-language

Some examples:

- Piece-of-ass
- Move that ass
- Haul your ass
- Your ass is mine
- I'm gonna beat your ass
- Get that ass in gear
- Get your ass over here
- put a cap in that ass
- cover my ass
- kick ass
- ass kicking
- ass kissing
- ass on the line
- ass whopping
- work your ass off

I've always wondered how there are so many phrases about asses and butts. Whereas Britain doesn't seem to have the same number of phrases about arses. Particularly as America was founded by purtians. 
Is this a linguistic thing or a cultural thing?

Weirdly some of the phrases would make more sense if they were talking about actual asses (as in donkeys) e.g. haul your ass. I wonder if that is the origin of some of these phrases.

Also phrases like "ass on the line" and "cover my ass". I find very strange, seeing as it's not just your ass on the line it's your whole body. And also why cover just the ass? And what about "your ass is mine"?

Comment: Why do the British constantly swear with reference to ... um .... butt _stuff_? 'Sod this' and 'bugger that'?

Comment: @Mitch Probably to do with the boarding school system in England. A lot of male on male behaviour there.

Comment: Surely you have been around small children as a parent, grandparent or relative and noticed the irresistible fascination they have for 'rude' words, especially those related to what in my childhood used to be called 'private parts?  And it seems that this fascination continues for many into adult life.  I have been struck, for example, by how strong a response there often is to questions involving reference to the lower human orifices.  It is not a mystery.  As a Brit, however, the word in question, as spelled,  means 'donkey'.  And that is a bit strange.

Comment: British and Australian people I know personally (I'm Australian), and British people on British television, say almost all of the examples you've given except for "put a cap" and "ass whooping". Except we typically say *arse* not *ass*.

Comment: In my opinion "haul your ass" makes less sense if you make it about a donkey: in that case it would be the ass doing the hauling, not being hauled.

Comment: @nnnnn only because Hollywood has made these very famous. British people rarely say "ass" except when imiting Americans. They might say "arse". Similarly we heard "butt" from Hollywood films.

Comment: @zooby - I did say that British and Australians say "arse" rather than "ass", but I think the two words are equivalent when used in the type of expressions you listed.

Comment: @nnnnn True, but I don't think these phrases were common in Britain before the 1980's. Similarly we heard "butt" from Hollywood films. As in "butt head" which I first heard in the tv show Wonder Years in about 1988. Instead British people would say "bum".  But now the word is quite common in Britain too. Just like we learned a lot of Australian slang from Neighbours like: barbie, maccers, ute, drongo, flaming galah, sheila, fair dinkum.

Comment: Because people in the US are still fond of the song "Danny Boy", sung to the tune "London Derrière".

Comment: Talking of Australian, we probably think Australians use the phrase "flaming galah" and "drongo" all the time. Where really they use "normal" swear words. But it's just because the writers are trying to use acceptable words. Another example is when a TV shows use other words like "plonker" as a made up swear word and it subsequently went into common languagae.

Answer (score 1):

Many of your examples are synecdoches. "a figure of speech in which a part is meant to represent the whole . . ." New Oxford American Dictionary.So, "The army put 200 boots on the ground." "All hands on deck." "Twenty head of cattle . . .'

Why that particular part of the anatomy is chosen to represent the whole may have to do with its sheer bulk in the English-speaking countries.

Comment: Well that might be true today with the obesity crisis. But I'm sure these were pretty popular sayings. I heard a lot of these in 1980's movies from Hollywood. And probably a lot are older than that.

Comment: I like the examples you give of "synecdoches". Maybe "ass" has just become the goto synecdoche when you want to sound a bit rude.

Comment: @zooby Yes, I'm sure rudeness is part of it. Also, it's a short, one-syllable word, which is also the case with most other words in the phrases.

Comment: I can imagine your phrases as "200 asses on the ground". "All asses on deck". "Twenty asses of cattle..." (maybe not)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the strong connotation of the term which,  in a Puritan context, may sound even stronger. It became popular in the US from the ‘30s:

***[Ass:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ass)***

> slang for "backside," first attested 1860 in nautical slang, ***in popular use from 1930; chiefly U.S.*** ; from dialectal variant pronunciation of arse (q.v.). The loss of -r- before -s- is attested in other words (burst/bust, curse/cuss, horse/hoss, barse/bass, garsh/gash). Indirect evidence of the change from arse to ass can be traced to 1785 (in euphemistic avoidance of ass "donkey" by polite speakers).

[Ass:](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ass)

> Literally, your ass is your buttocks. In slang, an ass is a jerk or an idiot. Neither is highly regarded.
>
> When people are being slangy or folksy, you hear this word a lot: "Get off your ass!" "Watch your ass!" "Why are you such an ass?" "Get your ass in here." ***Though this isn't one of the very worst swear words, it is considered harsher than butt*** and lots of people consider ass to be an inappropriate word. You would be a lot better off using softer words like bottom or tush in most situations. Sometimes ass can also mean sex — another use worth avoiding.

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: Interesting... so a lot of these phrases are fairly recent like 1930's onwards?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "jack-ass" refers to male donkeys.  Also with "you're a such an ass" (I belive is a British term comparing someone to a donkey.) Also as in "your father is an ass!"

Comment: @zooby - To have (one's) head up (one's) ass "not know what one is doing" is attested by 1969. Colloquial (one's) ass "one's self, one's person" attested by 1958. To work (one's) ass off "work very much" is by 1946; to laugh (one's) ass off "laugh very much" is by 1972 (implied from 1965). Ass-kissing (adj.) "currying favor" is by 1974.

Comment: Seems like a lot are quite recent. Perhaps these things just got popular in the same time as Hollywood movies got really big. And then they popularised the phrases further like a snowball effect. Could be that these phrases are just rude enough to get passed the censors so got used a lot in American movies as a type of acceptable swearing. Because you can say "ass" in a movie and still get a PG rating.

Comment: As an example, you can say "move your ass!" in a movie but not "get a f---ing move on you piece of sh--"